# Using setxkbmap to have | Hyper, Alt, Ctrl, Space-Bar, Ctrl, Alt, Hyper |

Tags: keymap, setxkbmap

Want to set a keyboard layout in the following way

```
Keys: Hyper, Alt, Ctrl, Space-Bar, Ctrl, Alt, Hyper
```

Perhaps using `setxkbmap`.  I use a US 104-Key Mechanical keyboard, and want a Dvorak Layout, with the key remapping as discussed.